# c# cannot access non static field anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> b;
    private IEnumerable<int> c;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> ds = new List<string>();

        ds.Sort((x, y) =>
        {
            b.Count();
            c.Count();
            return 1;
        });
    }
}
```

What is the reason for getting cannot access non-static field in static context ?

Comment: Why did you make `b` static but not `c`?

Answer (score 3):

`c` is an Instance field.  Instance members can not be accessed inside a Static method.  In order to access an Instance member, you need an Instance, and there isn't one inside a Static member.

For this to "work" you'd need to write 
`new Program().c.Count()` but this probably isn't what you want to do.

You could of course just make `c` static and everything would be fine.